# Add new style using REST api in geoserver

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I have worked with geoserver rest api and it is great, The only problem is that I have no idea how to post content of my sld using api, I have this code

```
public void AddNewStyle(String styledata, string workspace)
        {
            String requestUrl = RestServiceUrl + "/workspaces/" + workspace + "/styles";

            String status = String.Empty;

            object payload = styledata;

            try
            {
                status = SendRestRequest(requestUrl, RequestMethod.Post, typeof(WorkspaceRequest), ref payload, ContentType.Html, AcceptType.Json);
            }



            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Adding datastores failed.", ex);
            }
        }
```

this code works fine with other requests. the only problem is I dont know what to send as styledata. I have set styledata as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>Baft Farsode</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Name>BaftFarsoode</Name>
      <Title>بافت فرسوده</Title>
      <Abstract>BaftFarsoode area</Abstract>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
      <FeatureTypeName>Feature</FeatureTypeName>
        <Rule>
          <Title>بافت فرسوده</Title>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
             <ogc:PropertyName>Farsoode</ogc:PropertyName>
             <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
             <Fill>
                <!-- CssParameters allowed are fill (the color) and fill-opacity -->
                <CssParameter name="fill">#4DFF4D</CssParameter>
                <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.7</CssParameter>
             </Fill>     
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
         <Rule>
          <Title>بدون داده</Title>
          <ogc:Filter>

            <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
             <ogc:PropertyName>Farsoode</ogc:PropertyName>

            </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
             <Fill>
                <!-- CssParameters allowed are fill (the color) and fill-opacity -->
                <CssParameter name="fill">#ffffff</CssParameter>
                <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.7</CssParameter>
             </Fill>     
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

        <Rule>
          <Title>غیر فرسوده</Title>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    <ogc:PropertyName>Farsoode</ogc:PropertyName>
                    <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
             <Fill>
                <!-- CssParameters allowed are fill (the color) and fill-opacity -->
                <CssParameter name="fill">#FF4D4D</CssParameter>
                <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.7</CssParameter>
             </Fill>     
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

        <Rule>
          <Title>مرز املاک</Title>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.2</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
     </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

but it gives error, I think there must be another way to add style data as raw xml using rest api.

Can someone help me with this?

here is an example but it uploads sld file into geoserver. I want to send data as a raw string not by uploading.
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/examples/curl.html#creating-a-layer-style-sld-package

Comment: Did you ever get it solved?

Comment: @nathanvda yes, Content-type: text/xml should make it work

Comment: @MajidHojati Did you have any problem with unicode SLD expression ?

Comment: @MostafaFallah No, You have to enable unicode in you java installation and Jetti server.

Comment: @MajidHojati Thanks a lot Majid, But  i am using Windows Server that have Geo Server.

Comment: @MostafaFallah Geoserver is based on jetty(or tomcat) server which listens to port number 8080, if my memory serves me well, and both are java based. I guess in your configuration you are using windows server as proxy server for geoservices. so just configure your java version which is installed on the windows to add Unicode support.

Comment: @MajidHojati Thanks a lot Majid.

Comment: @MajidHojati based on your advise, my problem was fixed

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371140/unicode-problem-in-creating-style-with-rest-api-on-geoserver/371418#371418

Comment: @MostafaFallah nice, Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what libraries you are using but as the example you link to shows you need to send the sld file (zipped and encoded) to `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/styles` with the `Content-type` set.

I've never tried but I expect you could send just the XML data with a `Content-type: text/xml` but it will take longer than sending a compressed file.

Comment: Hi, I am using C#, I found the way, I am posting the answer

Answer (score 3):

If you're sure that .xml is valid (you can check its validation via [this online tool](https://jsonformatter.org/xml-viewer)) you need to add the following line to your request's header as mentioned in geoserver official documentation ([here](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#/latest/en/api/1.0.0/styles.yaml))

```
{content-type:'application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml'}
```

Here I give an example. First of all I created a **sld** string on my Node server using javascript:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <NamedLayer>
        <UserStyle>
        <Name>sld_tit_12</Name>
            <Title>No Title Existed.</Title>
            <Abstract>No Abstract Existed.</Abstract>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <Title>class_0</Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>tit_12</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                                <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:LowerBoundary>
                            <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                                <ogc:Literal>281</ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:UpperBoundary>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#fcd1a4</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">0.7</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#000</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
                <Rule>
                    <Title>class_1</Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>tit_12</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                                <ogc:Literal>281</ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:LowerBoundary>
                            <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                                <ogc:Literal>547</ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:UpperBoundary>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#fab072</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">0.7</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#000</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
                <Rule>
                    <Title>class_2</Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>tit_12</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                                <ogc:Literal>547</ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:LowerBoundary>
                            <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                                <ogc:Literal>905</ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:UpperBoundary>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#f6904c</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">0.7</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#000</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
                <Rule>
                    <Title>class_3</Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>tit_12</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                                <ogc:Literal>905</ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:LowerBoundary>
                            <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                                <ogc:Literal>2075</ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:UpperBoundary>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#d75538</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">0.7</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#000</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
                <Rule>
                    <Title>class_4</Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>tit_12</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                                <ogc:Literal>2075</ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:LowerBoundary>
                            <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                                <ogc:Literal>2889820</ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:UpperBoundary>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#914032</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">0.7</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#000</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

The above string is used to classify features on map. Then I made a request like this:

```
const geoserverRESTAPI = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/';
const options = {
   url: `${geoserverRESTAPI}styles`,
   method: 'POST',
   headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml' },
   body: sldString, //in string format
   auth: {
      user: '<username>',
      pass: '<password>'
   }
}
```

Don't forget to put your own username and password in *auth*.

If everything is OK, you will be received **201 - created** response.

Comment: Did you know what changes needs for working this code on UTF-8 ?

Comment: What problem do you have with UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: I described here my question. this is main problem that I can not have persian characters on the geo server style part.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371140/unicode-problem-in-creating-style-with-rest-api-on-geoserver?noredirect=1#comment606276_371140

Comment: Thanks Arash, My problem was fixed https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371140/unicode-problem-in-creating-style-with-rest-api-on-geoserver/371418#371418