# Unicode problem in creating style with REST API on GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, sld, geoserver-rest-api, unicode

I am creating some new style with Postman. The main problem is that the new style was created with Unicode problem. It means I am seeing the new style has some character that are not Unicode.

```
URL : http://localhost:8090/geoserver/rest/workspaces/webgis/styles

HTTP Post

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
  <NamedLayer>
<Name>export_output8464daf0723</Name>
<UserStyle>
<Title>export_output8464daf071</Title>
<Name>export_output8464daf0732</Name>
 <FeatureTypeStyle>
   <Rule>
       <Name>export_output8464daf071_site_name_1</Name>
       <Title>export_output8464daf071_site_name_1_تپه قورچی</Title>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>site_name</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>تست</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <PointSymbolizer>
          <Graphic>
         <Mark>
           <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
           <Fill>
             <CssParameter name="fill">#bd8321</CssParameter>
           </Fill>
         </Mark>
         <Size>2</Size>
       </Graphic>
     </PointSymbolizer>
   </Rule>
 </FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

and Content type is :

```
application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml
```

Style in GeoServer is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.0.0">
  <sld:NamedLayer>
    <sld:Name>export_output8464daf0732</sld:Name>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>export_output8464daf0732</sld:Name>
      <sld:Title>export_output8464daf071</sld:Title>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>export_output8464daf071_site_name_1</sld:Name>
          <sld:Title>export_output8464daf071_site_name_1_ط·ع¾ط¸آ¾ط¸â€، ط¸â€ڑط¸ث†ط·آ±ط¹â€ ط؛إ’</sld:Title>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>site_name</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>ط·ع¾ط·آ³ط·ع¾</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:PointSymbolizer>
            <sld:Graphic>
              <sld:Mark>
                <sld:WellKnownName>circle</sld:WellKnownName>
                <sld:Fill>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#bd8321</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Fill>
              </sld:Mark>
              <sld:Size>2</sld:Size>
            </sld:Graphic>
          </sld:PointSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: On my Ubuntu 20.04 box this works fine with curl and both ascii and binary data options. Are you on a windows machine by any chance?

Comment: @IanTurton Thank you .  Yes it is windows server ...

Comment: try "application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml;charset=UTF-8" as the content-type

Comment: I did it but the result is same :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of googling , I understood Java on windows does NOT support Unicode output by default. As we know, GeoServer made by JAVA too, so we have to do some stuff for fixing this issue.

**1. Add this variable to your System Environment Variable.**

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

**2. Open CMD (RUN AS Administrator) and run this command**

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>chcp 65001
```

and you will see this message : Active code page: 65001

**Point 1**  : Do not forget to restart your computer or 1 - close your explorer and open it and then 2 - restart you GeoServer service from Services.

**Point 2** : Your XML should be start with :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

**Point 3** : You do not need to add charset=UTF-8 in end of Content-Type. So you can set to :

```
Content-Type=application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml
```