# Problem with Geoserver SLD Style Encoding UTF-8 Chars

Tags: geoserver, style, sld, utf-8

I have installed Geoserver 2.20.1 with Java JDK 15.0.2 ON Windows Server 2012 R2, when i add a new SLD style including UTF-8, Geoserver does not understand UTF-8 chars
[image]

Comment: Geoserver doesn't support java 15,and Windows is notoriously poor at encoding

Answer (score 3):

You will need to adjust your java startup options to include the UTF encoding. -Djavax.servlet.response.encoding=​UTF-8. See the startup options specified in https://github.com/kartoza/docker-geoserver/blob/master/scripts/entrypoint.sh#L21

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with greek characters whene i was trying to export SLD file from qgis 3.28.x and import it via the style geoserver page that was in a windows server.This answer solved my problem [JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/371418/227809)